# jsonObject empty checkup in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

```
    url = loginInfo.settings.apiUrl & "sigma?machineId=" & If(production.machineId IsNot Nothing, Uri.EscapeDataString(production.machineId), Nothing)
    Dim jsonObj = Common.GetJson(url, loginInfo.token)
```

I have a jsonObject which get data through url and Getjson method.Empty JsonObj format has given bellow where main model is "mstSigmaVos"

```
{
  "type": "mstSigmaList",
  "error": false,
  "mstSigmaVos": [],
  "resourceMap": {
  "entry": []
 }
}
```

Previously I have validated above jsobObj like below code which is not working.

```
   If Not jsonObj("mstSigmaVos") Is Nothing Then
        'Do Something
    End If
```

My question is, why

```
If Not jsonObj("mstSigmaVos") Is Nothing Then
  'Do something
EndIf
```

or

```
 If jsonObj("mstSigmaVos")IsNot Nothing" Then
  'Do something
 EndIf
```

these checkup is not working for jsonObj check in vb?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this json validation problem by using bellow approach in vb.

```
 Dim hasJsonData = jsonObj("mstSigmaVos").count
 If hasJsonData > 0 Then
  'Do something
 EndIf
```

But just remain confusion why those VB validation "IsNot Nothing", "Not  Is Nothing" were not worked.

Comment: If these are strings you are testing, then a string can be empty but not null. .net has the `String.IsNullOrEmpty("your string")` to test for both. Also `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` will check beyond empty to multiple spaces or new linew.

Comment: But sorry to say that I am working with json object not String(although I mentioned above).so the validation check you mentioned those are not workable for me and it raise error

    "Conversion from type 'JObject' to type 'String' is invalid."